# reseting or clearing an input field with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I having the following problem.

I have a react component which does a filter search on a list which is fine, but I want to clear the input field with a button, if i add a value attribute to the input field which I can set in the setState but then it stops the onChange from working as it does the filter search on the list:

I've created the following but this still doesn't work.

```
<input type="text" ref="form" placeholder="Search indicators" className="uk-width-1-1" onChange={this.handleChange} />

<button className="uk-button uk-width-1-1" onClick="React.findDOMNode(this.refs.form).reset()"><i className="uk-icon-undo"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set the value to empty as

```
handleClick = () => {
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.form).value = "";
      }
```

and yes onClick expects a function or a value not a string. Also `React.findDOMNode()` is deprecated. You should use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode();`

```js
  
class Hello extends React.Component {
  handleChange = (e) => {
  
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.form).value = "";
  }
  render() {
    
    return (
      <div>
      <input type="text" ref="form" placeholder="Search indicators" className="uk-width-1-1" onChange={this.handleChange} />

<button className="uk-button uk-width-1-1" onClick={this.handleClick}><i className="uk-icon-undo"></i>click</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Also Its a better idea to use state and change the state for input value.

as

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super() 
      this.state = {
        valueAttr : ''
      
    }
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({valueAttr: e.target.value});
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({valueAttr: ''})
  }
  render() {
    
    return (
      <div>
      <input type="text" ref="form" placeholder="Search indicators" className="uk-width-1-1" value = {this.state.valueAttr} onChange={this.handleChange} />

<button className="uk-button uk-width-1-1" onClick={this.handleClick}><i className="uk-icon-undo"></i>click</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I personally prefer the second approach. But you can do it in whichever way you feel comfortable.

Comment: How to do it in a functional component

Comment: @yaswanthkoneri, for a functional component too, you can use state and refs with the help of hooks

Answer (score 1):

Here `onClick="React.findDOMNode(this.refs.form).reset()"` you are assigning string to onClick value of button, not a function, if you want to assign a function it should look like `onClick={React.findDOMNode(this.refs.form).reset}"` or `onClick={() => React.findDOMNode(this.refs.form).reset()}`

Next, if i recall correctly, `findDOMNode` is deprecated in React, so you should use ReactDOM for this.

And last, I doubt there is `reset` method present, so I think you should try mutating input value directly.

Try this

`onClick={() => this.refs.form.value = ''}`

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
this.refs.form.getInputNode().value = '';
```

Should do the trick